# How can I use multiple services in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am trying to build phonegap app using angularjs. Can I have more than one service per controller? If yes how do I inject them?

Comment: [Injecting Services Into Controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.injecting_controllers)... At least apply *some* effort before coming to SO with your issue.

Comment: @Andre I have read this. The doc doesn't describe it well. Can we do this for more than one service. I have written a working piece where I can get one service working but when I include second service it doesn't work. Though I haven't done using $inject

Comment: You haven't shared any code from your attempted solutions so it's impossible for anyone to gauge what you've tried and what you haven't.

Comment: Please share your exact problem. What you are asking is standard and available in documentation.

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Thanks http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.managing_dependencies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can dependency inject multiple services:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('MyController', [
        'Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3',
        function( Service1, Service2, Service3 ) {
          ...
        }
    ]);
```

Note that I'm using the [annotated syntax for the dependency injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) which is required if you plan on minifying or obfuscating your source code.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes when documentation isn't clear a simple example helps. Thanks again.